# Hello there, can pls someone explain me how exactly I can make a solution to get the full "Hello World" encrypted into the morse code?

Tags: python, morse-code

```
def encode( text, code_table, usecaps=True, insep="", outsep=" "):
    for x in text:
        if x != outsep:
            insep += code_table[x] + outsep
        return(code_table[x])

print(encode("Hello World", {'A': '.-', 'B': '-...', 'C': '-.-.',
        'D': '-..', 'E': '.', 'F': '..-.',
        'G': '--.', 'H': '....', 'I': '..',
        'J': '.---', 'K': '-.-', 'L': '.-..',
        'M': '--', 'N': '-.', 'O': '---',
        'P': '.--.', 'Q': '--.-', 'R': '.-.',
        'S': '...', 'T': '-', 'U': '..-',
        'V': '...-', 'W': '.--', 'X': '-..-',
        'Y': '-.--', 'Z': '--..',

        '0': '-----', '1': '.----', '2': '..---',
        '3': '...--', '4': '....-', '5': '.....',
        '6': '-....', '7': '--...', '8': '---..',
        '9': '----.'
        }))
```

Comment: Why are you returning inside the loop? That stops the loop after the first character.

Comment: Shouldn't you return `insep`? And why is that a parameter instead of a local variable?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach using (generator) comprehension and `dict.get`; I am not sure what `insep` and `outsep` are supposed to mean.

```py
def encode(text, code_table):
    return ''.join(code_table.get(c.upper(), c) for c in text)

# output: ......-...-..--- .-----.-..-..-..
```

Note that `code_table.get(..., c)` returns the input character `c` as is, if `c.upper()` is not in the dict `code_table`. In particular, a space character `' '` will be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to accomplish this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

code_dict = {
    'A': '.-', 'B': '-...',
    'C': '-.-.', 'D': '-..', 'E': '.',
    'F': '..-.', 'G': '--.', 'H': '....',
    'I': '..', 'J': '.---', 'K': '-.-',
    'L': '.-..', 'M': '--', 'N': '-.',
    'O': '---', 'P': '.--.', 'Q': '--.-',
    'R': '.-.', 'S': '...', 'T': '-',
    'U': '..-', 'V': '...-', 'W': '.--',
    'X': '-..-', 'Y': '-.--', 'Z': '--..',
    '1': '.----', '2': '..---', '3': '...--',
    '4': '....-', '5': '.....', '6': '-....',
    '7': '--...', '8': '---..', '9': '----.',
    '0': '-----', ', ': '--..--', '.': '.-.-.-',
    '?': '..--..', '/': '-..-.', '-': '-....-',
    '(': '-.--.', ')': '-.--.-', " ": " "
}


def encode(text, code_dictionary):
    # Create empty results variable to be returned once finished processing
    results = ""
    # For each in character in text.upper(). This will make the text uppercase so we can match our dictionary
    for character in text.upper():
        # This will append the value (morris code) from the character (key) from the morris code dictionary defined above 
        results += code_dictionary[character] + " "
    return results

#print the results of the definition
print(encode("Hello World", code_dict))
```

What you are trying to accomplish is looking up each letter within a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). More info on Dictionaries can also be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)

Note I added a white space to the `code_dict` variable so we can match spaces with spaces when evaluating within your encode definition.

There are probably a few thousand ways to accomplish what you are trying to do. This will help you understand how looking up key's within dictionaries, appending them to a [variable](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables.asp) using a [for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You should try to explain in what way your code is not working.  But, I suspect the problem is that your `return` statement is indented so that it is inside the `for` loop.  This means that the function will return after processing the first character.  You should unindent the `return` so that it will execute after the `for` loop is complete.

Comment: They're also returning the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to do it. You can iterate over the hw string and check to see if each letter is a key in morse_dict. I added the .upper() string method to account for the string containing a mix of upper and lowercase letters, while all the dict keys are uppercase.

```
morse_dict = {'A': '.-', 'B': '-...', 'C': '-.-.',
            'D': '-..', 'E': '.', 'F': '..-.',
            'G': '--.', 'H': '....', 'I': '..',
            'J': '.---', 'K': '-.-', 'L': '.-..',
            'M': '--', 'N': '-.', 'O': '---',
            'P': '.--.', 'Q': '--.-', 'R': '.-.',
            'S': '...', 'T': '-', 'U': '..-',
            'V': '...-', 'W': '.--', 'X': '-..-',
            'Y': '-.--', 'Z': '--..',
    
            '0': '-----', '1': '.----', '2': '..---',
            '3': '...--', '4': '....-', '5': '.....',
            '6': '-....', '7': '--...', '8': '---..',
            '9': '----.'
            }
    
hw = 'Hello World'

for x in hw:
    if x.upper() in morse_dict:
        print(x, morse_dict[x.upper()])
    else:
        print(' ')

H ....
e .
l .-..
l .-..
o ---
 
W .--
o ---
r .-.
l .-..
d -..
```

Answer (score 0):

Hrm... Maybe something like this assuming the input/output separator.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

code_dict = {
    'A': '.-', 'B': '-...',
    'C': '-.-.', 'D': '-..', 'E': '.',
    'F': '..-.', 'G': '--.', 'H': '....',
    'I': '..', 'J': '.---', 'K': '-.-',
    'L': '.-..', 'M': '--', 'N': '-.',
    'O': '---', 'P': '.--.', 'Q': '--.-',
    'R': '.-.', 'S': '...', 'T': '-',
    'U': '..-', 'V': '...-', 'W': '.--',
    'X': '-..-', 'Y': '-.--', 'Z': '--..',
    '1': '.----', '2': '..---', '3': '...--',
    '4': '....-', '5': '.....', '6': '-....',
    '7': '--...', '8': '---..', '9': '----.',
    '0': '-----', ', ': '--..--', '.': '.-.-.-',
    '?': '..--..', '/': '-..-.', '-': '-....-',
    '(': '-.--.', ')': '-.--.-', " ": " "
}


def encode( text, code_table, usecaps=True, insep="", outsep=" "):
    if usecaps:
        text = text.upper()
    else:
        return 'use caps must be true'
    for x in text:
        if x != outsep:
            insep += code_table[x] + outsep
    return insep

#print the results of the definition
print(encode("Hello World", code_dict))
```

Returning `code_table[x]` within the for loop will only return the first match. This is due to the return breaking out of the for loop.

Best of luck to you learning python!

Answer (score -1):

Ok ty already for the help, it was my first question here and I am pretty new to python and kinda struggle with easy things, but I will take notice for future. My biggest problem is that the code need to be solved with the exact parameter. The insep and outsep should define the input and output separator and must be backed up with a default value. I can´t really build your answers in my code and struggle to solve the problem of upper the letters in my code above and to not overwrite the output with the each following letter.